# D&D 4e - attack rolls - "level +x vs. defense" - clarification

Tags: dnd-4e, attack, attack-roll, keywords

I noticed that in the *Book of Vile Darkness*, for example, there are a lot of powers/diseases defined as "level+x vs. defense".

I want to be make sure I understand how these are rolled before I build some encounters: as I understand, you roll d20, then add the creature/disease's level, then the other mod. In this case, you might roll a 14 on the dice, add the level (7), then add a given mod (3) and get an attack roll of 24. Is this correct?

Comment: Could the title of this be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's how it works. You compare the total result to the listed defense, and if the total is equal or better than the defense, the attack hits.